# OnCreateOptionMenu does not work on Theme.Material.Light.Dialog theme

Tags: android

I met a problem in overflow menu. In general, the codes in MainActivity below will work on normal theme:

```
package pokon548.example;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // TODO: Implement this method
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        // TODO: Implement this method
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.item:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

and here is menu.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/item"
        android:title="Item"/>

</menu>
```

Also styles.xml:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">#FFEC5F67</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">#FFEC5F67</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">#FFEC5F67</item>

        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#FFEC5F67</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Layout file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

But if I changed theme from Theme.Material.Light to Theme.Material.Light.Dialog, Overflow menu button (three dots in ActionBar) will not be shown in Activity.

Is there's any ways to show Overflow menu in this situation?

Comment: share your `style.xml` and `layout` file

Comment: here is style.xml:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.Dialog">
  <item name="android:colorPrimary">#FFEC5F67</item>
  <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">#FFEC5F67</item>
  <item name="android:colorAccent">#FFEC5F67</item>
  
   <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#FFEC5F67</item>
  </style>
</resources>

Comment: and here is layout file:<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>

Comment: Do you have a toolbar in your layout?

Comment: not using it, just built-in Actionbar